# Monitoring Remote Folder over SFTP in a Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, daemon, sftp

As the title says, I need to monitor a remote folder for new files through a SFTP connection.

I setup a daemon process that opens a connection and if it finds any files then it retrieves their contents and if it doesn't then it sleeps for 5 seconds.  This works fine it just hovers around 4% CPU usage. Is there a better way to do this and is it bad to keep a connection like this open indefinitely?

Comment: Why can't you do the reverse? Setup a daemon on the server with the file that can use OS hooks to only be woken when the folder actually changes and then have it ping your app.

Answer (score 1):

That's probably the best thing you can do, given the circumstances. When watched directories get bigger, your daemon will likely run slower and consume more resources.

A single persistent connection is nothing, both on client and server. But if there are many clients, server may slow down.

If you control the other server, a much better way would be to install a daemon on it. Local process can listen to filesystem notifications and broadcast to connected watchers.